# Azure VMs using PowerShell Fails

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am creating a cluster of 160 Azure VMs using PowerShell. Script creates VMs in existing VNET and domain joins them.

Currently scripts runs fine, but it creates only 121 VMs instead of 160 and then fails with below error. As the script block is same for all the VMs, we are not sure if it is hitting any limit after 121 VMs (core/IP/etc.) that is preventing it from creating additional VMs.

```
Creating the virtual machine sw4CN-1049
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: The property 'SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
Exception Type: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
```

Comment: first world problems ;) well, after it fails, what happens when you try to create new vms? @Walter-MSFT it doesn't matter whats the vm size, any vm size will run out of default quota if you create 121 of those https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#subscription-limits

Comment: @Sajad Deyargaroo What your VM size?

Comment: You could check `Subscriptions --> Usage + quotas` on Azure Portal.  Check whether some resources hit the limit. More information please refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/skeeler/2017/01/30/subscription-usage-and-quotas-in-the-azure-portal/).

Comment: @4c74356b41  Yes, you are right. I want to know the OP the VM size and check if cores hit the limit.

Comment: Quotas have not hit the limit, I checked cores, cloud services and storage accounts and it seems none have hit the limit.